# Different Iteration outputs

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, iteration, concatenation

I have this in matlab

```
A=34;
for i =1:1:6
    A = A + 1;
t1=fix(A/(2*32));
t2=fix((A-(t1*64))/(32));
t3=fix(((A-(t1*64)) - (t2*32))/(16));
G = [t1 t2 t3]
end
```

When it displays, it gives

```
G= 0 1 0
G= 0 1 0
G= 0 1 0 ....to the 6th G(the values are not right anyway)
but I want to have an output of
G1= 0 1 0
G2= 0 1 0
G3= 0 1 0....to G6
```

and then cat.or put them into a set of G = [G1, G2, G3, ...,G6].Please how do I get this done?

Comment: I'm not a mathlab programmer, anyway I try to help you. If you try to declare G as an array and do G[A] = [t1 t2 t3]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few points to address regarding your question...

### Preallocating arrays and matrix indexing:

If you want to save the values you generate on each iteration, you can [preallocate the array](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/preallocating-arrays.html) `G` as a 6-by-3 matrix of zeroes before your loop and then [index into a given row of the matrix](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) within your loop to store the values:

```
A = 34;
G = zeros(6, 3);  % Make G a 6-by-3 matrix of zeroes
for i = 1:6
  % Your calculations for t1, t2, and t3...
  G(i, :) = [t1 t2 t3];  % Add the three values to row i
end
```

### Vectorized operations:

In many cases you can avoid for loops altogether in MATLAB and often get a speed-up in your code by using [vectorized operations](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html). In your case, you can create a vector of values for `A` and perform your calculations for `t1`, `t2`, and `t3` on an element-wise basis using the [arithmetic array operators](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/arithmetic-operators.html) `.*` and `./`:

```
>> A = (35:40).';   %' Create a column vector with the numbers 35 through 40
>> t1 = fix(A./64);  % Compute t1 for values in A
>> t2 = fix((A-t1.*64)./32);         % Compute t2 for values in A and t1
>> t3 = fix((A-t1.*64-t2.*32)./16);  % Compute t3 for values in A, t1, and t2
>> G = [t1 t2 t3]  % Concatenate t1, t2, and t3 and display

G =

     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
     0     1     0
```

The bonus here is that `G` will automatically end up as a 6-by-3 matrix containing all the values you want, so no preallocation or indexing is necessary.

### Displaying output:

If you want to create formatted output that differs from the default display of numbers that occurs when you leave off the semicolon at the end of a line, you can use functions like [`fprintf`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fprintf.html). For example, to get the output you want you could run this after creating `G` as above:

```
>> fprintf('G%d = %d %d %d\n', [1:6; G.'])  %' Values are drawn column-wise
G1 = 0 1 0                                   %   from the second argument
G2 = 0 1 0
G3 = 0 1 0
G4 = 0 1 0
G5 = 0 1 0
G6 = 0 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly your problem is just the output (so that all values are stored in G), right?

You might try this:

```
lowerbound = (i-1)*3 + 1;
G(lowerbound:lowerbound + 2) = [t1 t2 t3]
```

This should expand G with the newly computed values

Comment: yes, my problem is in the outputs, I tried your answer, I got his error                                                            ???  In an assignment  A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and
 I must be the same.

Error in ==> alot at 11
G(lowerbound:lowerbound + 3) = [t1 t2 t3]...

Comment: It must be G(lowerbound:lowerbound + 2), sorry typo... because you only add 3 elements (lowerbound, lowerbound+1 and lowerboubd +2)

Comment: Thanks for that, but the output I need is just serial G1 to G6 with 3 output elements as I described earlier,using the your syntax still gave me G with increasing output length which I dont want..Thank for answering...